# Can only feel clavicular head (upper chest) working out during inclined pushups

Tags: push-ups

Are inclined pushups good for the whole chest or it only targets upper chest?

Comment: I think what you mean is decline pushups.  Incline means that your feet are lower than your head, and decline is where your feet are raised above your head.

Answer (score 1):

Every chest exercise works the whole chest, but some exercises work more upper than lower. Incline push-ups tend to work more on the lower chest, and decline push-ups tend to target the upper chest. It's generally a good idea to do an equal amount of incline and decline exercises to prevent any possible imbalances over the long term.

Comment: What sort of imbalances can you get by doing just one?  Something like more pecs, and less abs?

Comment: More like excessive pec major (upper chest) development and less pec minor (lower chest) development, or vice versa. It's not something you have to worry about too much, as this generally happens only when your training plan is very imbalanced.